# Javascript Regex Pattern Capture

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to write a Javascript Regular Expression to find KEY (Page Number) for any given word 
For example in the paragraph below

```
Key for Chota = 1
Key for Seven = 1 & 2
Key for wonder =3
```

(Its like finding which all pages have a word on it)

---

```
||1||
Jam Jam jambura jadu tu sikh le aisa
Chota Bheem and Kisna Seven
||2||
One Two Three Bla Bla Bla
Nine Eight Seven Laa Laa Laa
||3||
twinkle twinkle little star
how I wonder what you are
```

---

I wrote following expression but it is not working properly

```
/(?:\|\|)(\d+)(?=\|\|)(?=(.|\n)*wonder)/img;
```

Comment: You don't want regular expressions.  Please give us a sample of your html that shows the key that is to be returned when there is a match.

Comment: @DerekHenderson what HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `(.|\n)*` can go beyond the next `||n||`. You need to avoid that, usually by nesting a negative lookahead inside the repetition:

```
/\|\|(\d+)(?=\|\|(?:(?!\|\|\d+\|\|)[\s\S])*wonder)/ig;
```

Note that I replaced `(.|\n)` with `[\s\S]`, because the former will not get past other line break characters like `\r` and some Unicode ones. `[\s\S]` is the standard way to match "any character" (in fact, in Javascript you could also use `[^]` (not no character)).

Also note that the `m` modifier is irrelevant here, since it only affects how `^` and `$` match (both of which are not part your regex).

As for the expression, before consuming each character in the repetition we check with a lookahead, that it does not mark the start of a `||n||`.

[Working demo.](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gi&regex=%5C%7C%5C%7C%28%5Cd%2b%29%28?=%5C%7C%5C%7C%28?%3a%28?!%5C%7C%5C%7C%5Cd%2b%5C%7C%5C%7C%29%5B%5Cs%5CS%5D%29%2aseven%29&input=%7C%7C1%7C%7C%0AJam%20Jam%20jambura%20jadu%20tu%20sikh%20le%20aisa%0AChota%20Bheem%20and%20Kisna%20Seven%0A%7C%7C2%7C%7C%0AOne%20Two%20Three%20Bla%20Bla%20Bla%0ANine%20Eight%20Seven%20Laa%20Laa%20Laa%0A%7C%7C3%7C%7C%0Atwinkle%20twinkle%20little%20star%0Ahow%20I%20wonder%20what%20you%20are)

Comment: m.buettner You are awesome.

Comment: Special thanks for the explanation and working Demo

Comment: Would you mind helping me one more time?

Comment: In the same example, is it possible to also perform following operation?                                                                             I also want to capture surrounding 2 words (on right and left) of the searched word. I have a working regex for this

Comment: (?:[^\|.\s\r\n]*[\s\r\n]+){0,2}(?:[^\s\r\n]*)wonder(?:[^\s\r\n]*)(?:[\s\r\n]+[^\|.\s\r\n]*){0,2}                                         Now I want to combine both regex to get PAGE NUMBER & Surrounding text                                                                               ex. 3,how I wonder what you

Comment: @SuyogBarve try just wrapping that expression of yours in parentheses and replace `wonder` with it.

Comment: thanks a lot, All I can say is !!!!You are Awesome!!!!

Comment: @ m.buettner: I need one more help, can you please take a look at this post-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574721/javascript-regex-pattern-capture-all-possible-combinations