# Javascript Regex Pattern Capture - all possible combinations

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regular expression

```
\|\|(\d+)(?=\|\|(?:(?!\|\|\d+\|\|)[\s\S])*jambura)
```

[Working Sample](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gis&regex=%5C%7C%5C%7C%28%5Cd%2B%29%28%3F%3D%5C%7C%5C%7C%28%3F%3A%28%3F!%5C%7C%5C%7C%5Cd%2B%5C%7C%5C%7C%29%5B%5Cs%5CS%5D%29%2ajambura%29&input=%7C%7C1%7C%7C%0AJam%20Jam%20jambura%20jadu%20tu%20sikh%20jambura%20le%20aisa%0AChota%20Bheem%20and%20Kisna%20Seven%0A%7C%7C2%7C%7C%0AOne%20Two%20Three%20Bla%20Bla%20Bla%0ANine%20Eight%20Seven%20jambura%20Laa%20Laa%20Laa%0A%7C%7C3%7C%7C%0Atwinkle%20twinkle%20jambura%20little%20star%0Ahow%20I%20wonder%20jambura%20what%20you%20are)
Can someone please help me to find all possible combinations in using regex

Details:
The current regex is able to capture WIDEST MATCHES (within a given page), but it is unable to capture embedded/substring patterns
ex: regex is able to capture ||1|| for

```
 ||1||     
 Jam Jam jambura jadu tu sikh jambura
```

but it is unable to capture it for

```
 ||1||     
 Jam Jam jambura
```

Basically I want to write a pattern which should be able to find page numbers on which a given word occurs. So if word "jambura" occurs twice on Page ||1||, I should be able to capture 2 matches.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In JavaScript the most practical solution is to match the entire page (change `(?=...)` into `...`, remove `jambura`) and then match `jambura` in the result.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```
var str='||1|| Jam Jam jambura jadu tu sikh jambura';
reg = /(?!\|\|(\d+)\|\||jambura).+?jambura/g;
re = /(?![\|]+)\d+(?=[\|]+)/
alert('page '+str.match(re)+': '+str.match(reg).length+' matches');
```

**[Try Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/cgMen/2/)**

the idea is to match `\|\|\d+\|\|` first, then only `jumbara`. Actually, I spent half of a night to find a solution, so I don't remember why I started to use `?!` here, but it works

Comment: I really appreciate the effort you have put in, but the solution proposed by you is not what I am looking for. I want only one regex pattern which should be able to return "n" matches, each match for occourance of word. Example if jambura occurs 2 times I should be able to get str.match(reg)[0] = 1 and str.match(reg)[1] = 1

Comment: @SuyogBarve what's a problem? `str.match(reg).length` returns number of matches, you don't need an array filled with `1`